# roscd can't see my OpenCV package

Tags: ros, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
.I've set my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to "/home/leo/:/home/leo/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks"

Now when I do roscd opencv2 it leads me to the package opencv2 but when i type roscd OpenCV it says "roscd: No such package/stack 'OpenCV'"
but that package OpenCV is definetly there I'm seeing it in my "/opt/ros/hydro/share/".What could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143151/roscd-can%27t-see-my-opencv-package/) by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2014-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no **ROS** package OpenCV. Look inside the folder `/opt/ros/hydro/share/OpenCV`. There is no package.xml. OpenCV is a conventional library that is packaged as ROS package opencv2 for convenience of installation.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) on 2014-03-23**:
Thanks pal.Your answer gives me a better understanding.